# SSRS2016 external parameters for mobile report

Tags: ssrs, sql-server-2016, parameter, ssrs-2016, mobile-reports

How can external parameters be passed to a SSRS 2016 mobile report in order to pre-select values / settings for the report?

The same scenario is possible for paginated reports as it always was. It's one of the key functionalities.

In my scenario I need to integrate the reports into an existing application. So some settings like USERID or LANGUAGE must be passed to the integrated report to initialize it correctly. It's not tolerable to expect a user of the application to choose a language every time he/she runs a report inside of the application...

Besides setting parameters for the datasets within the mobile report I could not find any option to take values from external / url...? 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft help suggested:

```
.../<report-name>?<dataset-name>.<field-name>=<parameter-value>
```

Its seems SSRS does support parameters in the url, 
[here is a starting point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/mobile-reports/add-parameters-to-a-mobile-report-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)